# Spring Integration / Spring cloud Stream : How to send a single message using @inboundchanneladapter

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I have the following piece of code :

```java
 @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = Source.OUTPUT, poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "${fixedDelay}", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
    public MessageSource<String> timerMessageSource() {
        logger.info("Sending Message");
        return () -> new GenericMessage<>(new SimpleDateFormat().format(new Date()));
    }
```

I wish to disable the poller so that i can send a single message out. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

That wouldn't make this application a `stream` :-) You might just write a [task](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task) that sends a single message out.

Comment: Found an example on one of the stackoverlfow posts.

Answer (score -1):

Code:

```
 public interface MessageChannels {

   @Output("activationMsgQueue")
    MessageChannel save();
 }
```

Code:

```
@Service
@EnableBinding(MessageChannels.class)
public class CloudStreamProducer implements MessageSender {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(CloudStreamProducer.class);

    @Autowired
    MessageChannels msgChannel;

    public void sendMessage(ActivationDataInfo msg) {
        msgChannel.save().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(msg).build());
        LOGGER.info("Sent Activation Message to apt Topic : Acct NO = " + msg.getAcctNo()
            + " TN = " + msg.getTn() + " FlowType = " + msg.getFlowType());
    }

}
```

Comment: Would you like to augment your code-only answer with some explanation? it would probably improve it noticeably.